# Xamarin Forms - Navigation stack disrupted when send email

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

My cross-platform Xamarin Forms app (iOS and Android) needs to send an email (upon request from the user). Right now, when the user presses the appropriate button I'm calling

```
Page.Navigation.PushAsync(new SendEmailPage)
```

And then in the SendEmailPage constructor I'm using the DependencyService to send an email:

```
IMail mail = DependencyService.Get<IMail> ();
mail.SendMessage ("Contents");
```

I've implemented IMail in both Android and iOS, but looking just at the Android version:

```
void IMail.SendMessage (string contents)
{
   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
   emailIntent.SetType ("message/rfc822");
   emailIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraEmail, new string [] { "me@notreal.com" });
   emailIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject");
   emailIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraText, contents);
   Forms.Context.StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (emailIntent, "Send email"));
}
```

When I run this code, and click the appropriate button, it pops up an email "Compose" window with all the appropriate information filled in, and I can click the "send" button to send the mail. Cool!

Side Question: Am I correct in assuming there's no way to send an email "quietly" (without requiring additional user intervention)? This would not be something done maliciously, our app would only do this when the user asked to, and would certainly request the appropriate privileges if this is possible.

Main Question #1: When the "Compose" window comes up, if I click the back button in the title bar, it takes me back to my email Inbox, not back to my application. How do I invoke the email intent/activity in such a way that its back button brings the user back to my app?

Main Question #2: Instead, when the "Compose" window comes up, if I click the back button in the bottom of the screen, it does come back to my app, but tells me "Message saved as draft" which isn't what I want. I would rather have the message deleted, and then re-create it if the user hits the appropriate button again.

Answer (score 0):

For Main Question #1, I believe that starting the activity with

```
Forms.Context.StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (emailIntent, "Send email"));
```

instead of:

```
Forms.Context.StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (emailIntent, "Send email"));
```

should work to get you back to your Forms activity. At least in a non-forms app that should work, and I suspect it should in a Form app as well, but not 100% certain.

I can not answer your side question, though I suspect that this is intentional. I am sure you are not intending to do anything malicious and that the user requests the email, but if the OS allowed sending the email without user interaction, developers who are not as ethical as you might abuse the feature. But don't quote me, there may very well be a way to do it, I just don't know how if so.

As for Main Question #2, without changing the behavior of the email client app, I don't see how you could do as you wish as it is the mail client itself that is saving the email as a draft.

Comment: Alas no ... (1) Forms.Context isn't an Activity but I can cast it to an Activity.  (2) When I call activity.StartActivityForResult the behavior is the same.